# VB.net mix items of the listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, random

I made a puzzle app, you firstly choose an image from your computer then you click start and it takes parts of the image and adds them to a listview. Then you take images from listview and put them in the free spaces.But the problem is in the listview, images are ordered(right to left and top to bottom of the image parts).

My question here is how can I mix randomly items(images) inside of my listview?

Comment: You have to *shuffle* the pieces before you add them to the listview.  Just like you'd shuffle a deck of cards.  Just google that, query "vb.net random shuffle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I found how to do that:
I have created a new listview and named it listview2(first one was listview1).
Then I've added all images to listview2 not lv1, after I randomly add the items of the lv2 to lv1 and it worked

For i = 0 To ListView2.Items.Count - 1
            Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((ListView2.Items.Count - 1)*Rnd()))

```
        ListView1.Items.Add(ListView2.Items(value).Text, ListView2.Items(value).ImageIndex)
        ListView2.Items(value).Remove()
    Next i
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to take the puzzle apart in random order then store it in the LV.  To do this, you'll have to assign an index value to each puzzle piece, like an ID.  Use this to take the puzzle apart and know which one they selected.

This will create a List(Of Integer) which would represent the puzzle IDs, then shuffles it:

```
Function RandomList(MaxVal As Integer) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim rand As New Random()

    Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim temp As Integer
    Dim ndxRand As Integer

    For n As Integer = 0 To MaxVal - 1
        list(n) = n
    Next

    For thisNDX As Integer = 0 To MaxVal - 1
        ndxRand = rand.Next(thisNDX, MaxVal)
        temp = list(ndxRand)
        list(ndxRand) = list(thisNDX)
        list(thisNDX) = temp
    Next thisNDX

    Return list
End Function
```

Use it something like this:

```
Dim list As List(Of Integer) = RandomList(PieceCount)

For n As Integer = 0 To PieceCount - 1
    puzzlePiece = Puzzle.ReMovePiece(List(n))

    AddPieceToLV(puzzlePiece)
Next n
```

Of course this is just a guess since we have no idea what the code looks like.

Randomizing an LV directly is problematic for various reasons.  I imagine the pieces are images, and I have no idea how one would sort images; you'd have to assign a value to them to sort.  Next, the LV natively only sorts by Item not SubItems, which is where the image likely is so they display in LgIcon view(? ... guessing).  Next, the LV only does a Text sort (unless you also write a ListViewItemSorter) which will be a problem with a piece count over 10.  Much easier to take it apart and store it randomly.